# Hard Edges On Corners

Tags: modeling

I have a model with a smooth curve, and on the front of the model, I extruded the faces inwards, I trying to make the edges less curved, so they look like a rectangle. So I added support loops, which minimise the smoothness on the edges, but it alters the smoothness of the curved mesh. Is there a method to get the edges more harder?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using creases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the edges that should be sharp and use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to adjust the [*Edge Crease*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#edge-crease). This controls the weight used for the edge by the subdivision surface modifier. Alternatively you can also control the value in the sidebar. Open the sidebar with <kbd>N</kbd> *> Item > Transform* and change the value for *Crease*.

[image: Before]

[image: Increasing edge crease]

[image: After]

Comment: Hi Robert, 

Thanks for your reply, this method Shift E( Egde Crease) did work, but also required the inner edges to be selected as well, to get the selected mesh to look all squared up.

https://ibb.co/7XkmRVY

Kind Regards,